# Does a sequence in $\mathbb R$ with this condition $2a_n \leq a_{n-1}+ a_{n+1}$ satisfy this convergence?

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose I have a sequence {$a_n$} $\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ which is bounded and satisfies the following condition: $2a_n \leq a_{n-1}+ a_{n+1}$. Why is it that $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_{n})$= 0?

Comment: It suffices to show that the sequence a_n_ converges, right? Maybe if you assume it diverges you'll get a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inequality $$2a_n \leq a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}$$ can be rearranged to $$a_n-a_{n-1} \leq a_{n+1}-a_n,$$ so we have that $b_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$ is bounded monotone sequence, and thus convergent (boundedness is due to triangle inequality).

Let $L$ be the limit of $(b_n)$. If $L>0$, then there exists $n_0$ such that $b_n > 0$, for all $n\geq n_0$, and thus $(a_n)$ is monotone for $n\geq n_0$. But, $(a_n)$ must be convergent as well in that case, so $$\lim_n b_n = \lim_n (a_{n+1}-a_n) = 0$$ Contradiction. Similarly for $L<0$. We conclude that $\lim_n (a_{n+1}-a_n) = 0$, as wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!

Comment: @Buklau, you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let $b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$. From the condition $2a_n \leq a_{n-1}+ a_{n+1}$ we get $b_n \leq b_{n+1}$. {$b_n$} is bounded because there exists $M$ such that $b_n=a_n-a_{n-1} \leq M+M$.

To conclude, {$b_n$} is increasing and bounded above, thus it is convergent.

Comment: This does not provide full answer to the question. You must show that $\lim_n b_n = 0$.

Comment: This solves it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Case 1. $a_{n-1}<a_{n+1}$ Then
$$
\eqalign{
& 2a_n<a_{n-1}+a_{n+1} < 2a_{n+1} \cr
& \rightarrow a_n < a_{n+1} \cr
}
$$
Case 2. $a_{n-1} > a_{n+1}$ Then
$$
\eqalign{
& 2a_n < a_{n-1}+a_{n+1} < 2a_{n-1} \cr
& \rightarrow a_n < a_{n-1} \cr
}
$$
In both cases monotonicity is implied, therefore convergence.

Comment: Your conclusion doesn't seem to be true. What you can conclude is that if $a_{n-1}<a_{n+1}$ *for all* $n$, then $(a_n)$ would be monotone, and similarly for the second case. What is overlooked is that both cases can happen for the same sequence, but different $n$'s.

Comment: Probably you are right. It is not clear at this stage.

Comment: All I'm saying is that monotonicity can't be derived this way. Take for example sequence $0, -2, -3, -3, -2, 0, 3,\ldots$

Comment: I agree Ennar. I used the cases like "for all n". Sorry, it was a fast answer but erroneous.